# Flexbox overflow hidden

Tags: css, overflow, flexbox

How can I achieve `overflow hidden` when using `flexbox` instead of `floats`?

My flex example on codepen: [using flexbox](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyzRMQ?editors=1100)

My float example on codepen, this is what I want but with flexbox: [using floats](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MygpPw?editors=1100)

Comment: It's a image gallery. Thumbs on left and large on right. Obviously the left thumbs are to be scrollable vertically at some later point.

Comment: It looks like you solved my problem, thank you @Paulie_D :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that flexbox will make the columns equal height or at least the largest will take precedence when expanding the parent.

So, we need to collapse the left div by effectively removing the content..and the easiest method for that is `position:absolute`.

So we wrap the content in an extra element inside the left div and position it as mentioned...then allow overflow scrolling as required.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.thumbs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 26%;
  border: 10px solid green;
  position: relative;
  overflow-Y: auto;
}
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.large {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="thumbs">
    <div class="wrap">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-700-700-8.jpg">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-700-700-5.jpg">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-700-700-4.jpg">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-700-700-10.jpg">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-700-700-10.jpg">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-700-700-9.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="large">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-700-700-8.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```